# what wrong with this code as it's giving error?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
set serveroutput on
DECLARE
  V_IND_NAME VARCHAR(100);
  V_CREATE INTEGER := 1;
BEGIN
    select max(index_name) into V_IND_NAME from USER_INDEXES I where TABLE_NAME='ETL_TXN_Q'
    and (select count(1) from USER_IND_COLUMNS C where c.table_name = i.table_name and c.index_name = i.index_name) = 2
    and (select c.column_name from USER_IND_COLUMNS C where c.table_name = i.table_name and c.index_name = i.index_name and c.COLUMN_POSITION=1) = 'ETQ_SID'
    and (select c.column_name from USER_IND_COLUMNS C where c.table_name = i.table_name and c.index_name = i.index_name and c.COLUMN_POSITION=2) = 'PROCESSED_STATUS';
   
    IF V_IND_NAME = 'ETQ_ETQ_SID_PROCESSD_STATUS_UK' THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Index is correct and No Action Needed');
        V_CREATE := 0;
    ELSIF V_IND_NAME is NOT NULL THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Index ' || V_IND_NAME || ' exists with different name on same columns do drop it');
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP index ||V_IND_NAME';
    END IF;
   
    IF V_CREATE = 1 THEN
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Creating index ETQ_ETQ_SID_PROCESSD_STATUS_UK...');
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create unique index ETQ_ETQ_SID_PROCESSD_STATUS_UK on etl_txn_q (etq_sid,processed_status) tablespace &ITS_INDEX';
    END IF;
END;
/
```

> Output error:
> ERROR at line 22:
> ORA-06550: line 22, column 4:
> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:
> if

Comment: Change `ENDIF` to `END IF`. I have edited it but then it will be in queue for approval. Kindly check if you see the edit.

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 you edited the problem out of the question, you should not do that.

Comment: @Gimby, My mistake. I didn't know that was a real mistake and was the main cause of the issue.

Comment: Thanks for help, have modified above script as suggested and it's worked! :)

Answer (score 2):

check: `ENDIF` is needed to be `END IF`.

Comment: @Nikolas - how does it not provide an answer?  It _is_ the correct answer, though the problem itself was removed from the question by Sujitmohanty30.